# Does it make sense to host media on a .onion site on the darknet, or can I link to lightweb as well?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, html, web-development, privacy

There is a resource on the light web (normal Internet), hosted on multiple servers and subdomains. Let's nominally call servers `A` (main, with code) and `B` (auxiliary, with photos and videos), and the domains are named, respectively, `example.com` and `media.example.com`.

The `example.com` has a mirror in the darknet (which is also hosted on server `A` and refers to the same folder), let it be `example.onion`. `media.example.com` which is on server `B` could have (but does not yet have) a mirror `mediawebsite.onion`.
At the moment all the photos on `example.onion` have the format:

```
<img src="https://media.example.com/image.jpeg" alt="" />
```

Of course, even if `media.example.com` is blocked in the user's country, everything loads fine through the TOR network.
The question is: Does it make sense to convert all the media links on `example.onion` from `media.example.com/...` to `mediawebsite.onion/...` and if so, which one?

Comment: I think a "best practice" should be that onion sites serve ALL of their content (js, css, images, all possible links, etc) from a hidden service, and never serve their own content from the clear web if absolutely possible. Aside from things like `OnionTrafficOnly` or other security measures that might block those resources, if someone is using an onion site, they prefer anonymity and the onion domains provide extra peace of mind. Additionally, this reduces the chances a malicious exit tries to mess with any non-Tor related requests from the .onion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out, Tor has an OnionTrafficOnly setting. Also, if the site contains links to non-Tor resources, an "exit" is used, which slows down the data download considerably. Thus, it is really necessary to link to the photo as follows:

```
<img src="http://mediawebsite.onion/image.jpeg" alt="" />
```

instead of:

```
<img src="https://media.website.com/image.jpeg" alt="" />
```